# Mongodb commands to perform operations on server side Database

Tags: ios, mongodb, parsing, parse-server

I have migrated my database from parse.com to monogodb. Through my MAC machine terminal, I am able to export/import data to mongodb which is reside on mongo server.

How can I drop table or delete rows from the server side database through terminal commands?

I have following commands in mongo/bin folder. Here I have attached the snapshot.

[image: Monogo list of commands]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Connect with the remote mongo database through terminal this is the correct command:

$./mongo ds012345.mlab.com:12345/dbName -u username -p password

You need to run this command in ./mongo/bin folder.

and after this command connection will be established and you can run mongo shell commands on remote database.

Answer (score 0):

robomongo allows you to connect with remote db. you can specify your server ip in robomongo. it gives you a proper gui to delete to rows or collection. otherwise you need to create an api to delete that particular rows and tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to a remote instance with mongo by specifying an ip like follows, replacing the imaginary ip 10.11.12.128 with your own:

```
mongo 10.11.12.128
```

This works if you don't have a firewall blocking connections and if your mongod is running on the default port 27017. If you use a non-default port, for example 27018, you can specify that in your connection:

```
mongo 10.11.12.128:27018
```

Mongo shell is a powerful tool. You can do everything you asked for, copy database data, drop collections (=tables) or documents (=rows). You can find the documentation and all commands on the MongoDB pages:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/

Comment: Here is the command to connect to remote database :  mongo -u <user> -p <pass> --host <host> --port 28015, What would be the value of <host>here ? and after the connection can I able to alter my remote database through monog shell?

Comment: <host> is the ip address or hostname if you have one. And yes, you can alter the remote database through the mongo shell after connecting. Do note that you need to choose the correct database unless you use the default. You can do this with `use <databasename>` command.